# C# : RowUpdating Method not called when Update is clicked in a gridView

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-3.5, gridview

I am having a gridView which has a Edit, Delete, Update and Cancel  link buttons to perform the respected functionalities.

Edit, Delete and Cancel commands work fine.

But the problem is that the `RowUpdating` Event is not fired when I click Update Link Button on the gridView.

What could be wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCompanies" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" 
            onpageindexchanging="gvCompanies_PageIndexChanging" 
            onrowediting="gvCompanies_RowEditing" PageSize="20" 
            onrowcancelingedit="gvCompanies_RowCancelingEdit" 
            onrowdeleting="gvCompanies_RowDeleting" 
            onrowupdating="gvCompanies_RowUpdating" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="name" ItemStyle-Width="200px" 
                    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Name" >
               <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="200px"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="address" HeaderText="Address">
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="200px" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="city" ItemStyle-Width="200px" 
                    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="City" >
                 <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="200px"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="state" ItemStyle-Width="200px" 
                    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="State" >
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="200px" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="zipcode" HeaderText="Zip Code" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="telephone" HeaderText="Telephone" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="fax" HeaderText="Fax" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="mobile" HeaderText="Mobile" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="website" HeaderText="Website" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="Email" />
                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

In .cs file My RowUpdating Event is as below

```
    protected void gvCompanies_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        //My Code for Update
    }
```

**NOTE:** I had checked out all the similar questions on Stackoverflow but none seem to work for me. So I had posted this question

Comment: Its working fine when i implement your code. Did you apply gvCompanies.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex; in RowEditing

Comment: @John K:  I didnt find any option like "ShowUpdateButton" in GridView.

Comment: @Fraz Sundal: Yes I have implemented that and my Edit, Delete and Cancel buttons respond to there events but only update is not working

Comment: Apologies, I was wrong about that and was thinking of something different - ShowUpdateButton not in the GridView control because its behaviour (along with Cancel) is automatic based on the Edit button. Please ignore what I said. (I've deleted my comment because it's noise).

Comment: @John K: Thanks John. Not an issue. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the answer.

Thanks to those who tried to help me with this.

Had to change `CausesValidation` property  of my commandButton to `false`.

Hope this helps all.

Comment: Thank You, this is exactly the problem I was having!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Try replacing:

```
<asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
```

With:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton CommandArgument="" CommandName="Edit" runat="server" Text="Edit"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="False" ShowDeleteButton="true" />
```

ADD OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand1" to your datagrid:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCompanies" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True"
        OnPageIndexChanging="gvCompanies_PageIndexChanging" OnRowEditing="gvCompanies_RowEditing"
        PageSize="20" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvCompanies_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDeleting="gvCompanies_RowDeleting"
        OnRowUpdating="gvCompanies_RowUpdating"
        OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="name" ItemStyle-Width="200px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                HeaderText="Name">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="200px"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="address" HeaderText="Address">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="200px" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="city" ItemStyle-Width="200px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                HeaderText="City">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="200px"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="state" ItemStyle-Width="200px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                HeaderText="State">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="200px" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="zipcode" HeaderText="Zip Code" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="telephone" HeaderText="Telephone" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="fax" HeaderText="Fax" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="mobile" HeaderText="Mobile" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="website" HeaderText="Website" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="Email" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and then add below:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand1(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
        string command = e.CommandName; //use this to get the button that was pressed i.e. edit/delete
}
```

Comment: `e.CommandName` does not catch the `Update` Command. Every other command is caught in `e.CommandName` and is working fine

Comment: That's weird, I checked it on myne now and it does catch it with e.CommandName is Edit

Comment: Have a look now and see if the template field works for the edit?